# How to retrieve data from multiple json files by making multiple ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

A year ago, I learned json and ajax in a training program. Now since I will be going on a similar job from next month, I want to practice whatever I learned. So I am making a Football page for various FIFA teams. On my home page there are various links like "Teams", "Players", "Clubs", "History" ...All of them are inter related to each other. I have 4 JSON files: teams.json, players.json, clubs.json, history.json. I am not able to understand how to perform multiple ajax calls to retrieve the information. Like when I click on "Players", the information of club of the player should come from Clubs.json. I hope I am able to make my problem clear.

Please ask if any doubts. I can also post the so-far written code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't have much experience, but what I think is that you will not have to get the data from json files most of the time like that if you are building a website or an app.

Instead there are probably going to be a backend service like API.

API can be made of PHP or Ruby on Rails and etc. It's purpose is to get all the data you need let's say for the link Players from all the different tables you have in the database, let's say Teams, Clubs and so on, and group them in a nice JSON string (you will need to parse it) sending it back to you.

And because of that you won't need to make a lot of ajax calls which is slow and heavy and you will leave that work for the backend logic making only one single ajax call.

So what you are trying to do is wrong in your case because for an app like that the data will be stored in database, not in json files.

You can search and read more about the API in google if you are interested.

This is my unprofessional opinion. Hope it helped you or motivated you to learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to achieve following task,
You have 4 pages."Teams", "Players", "Clubs", "History
When you click on Teams, you want to get data from Teams.json
When you click on Players, you want to get data from Players.json

You can write 4 different function

```
function getTeams(){
//ajax call to get Teams
}

function getPlayers(){
//ajax call to get Players
}
```

etc

Comment: Ok I get your point. I get the data from "teams.json" in function getTeams(). Suppose in getTeams() I only display 20 players of the team, so now I want these players names displayed should be links to individual player information to be retrieved from "players.json". So I am stuck at how to do this. I am able to make the names of players as links. But how to redirect their names to players.json to get their individual info!!

In players.json, I have placed Player name, Player playing Start date, and teams which he plays with.